# Fill larger polygon empty space with closest subset of polygons

Tags: vector, polygon-creation, voronoi-thiessen, proximity

Looking for an ArcGIS or QGIS solution.

[image]

I need to divide up the space of the large single green polygon. Each new polygon would  represent "nearness" to the purple polygons and have the ID of the purple Polygon it is closest to. Need to fill all the empty green space.

This would be a Thiessen Polygons solution if the purple were point but my input is a polygon and I need the equivalent but "what polygon am I closest to" and the ID of the original polygon has to carry over to the new closest polygons. I am open to turning the purple polygons into raster and having a raster solution.

I know I can turn the polygon boundary into equally spaced point and do this but I am looking for something more elegant and fully accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found it.

Raster Euclidean Allocation works with both raster and vector inputs and I think will divide the space up as I need it.

Comment: we recommend longer answers that explain why.

Comment: +1 I see no reason for a more elaborate answer: the question itself quite clearly describes Euclidean Allocation; all that remained was to recognize that.

Comment: I found the answer in one of whubers earlier answers on this site about the same problem I was having above but with lines as opposed to Polygons.

Comment: I think adding a link to that earlier answer by whuber would be appropriate.  You can copy/paste a direct link to it via the **share** button beneath the answer.